# How can I manually generate a fake ACPI lid event from a script in linux?

Tags: linux, script, acpi, events

I'm trying to make sure that my laptop will suspend if I unplug it after the lid is already closed, and I believe that one way to accomplish this would be to simulate an ACPI lid event when the power adapter is plugged or unplugged. In order to do this, I need to find a command that will generate a fake ACPI lid event. Is there any such command?

Comment: Couldn't you just close your lid and unplug it and wait a moment. Then open your lid? If it was suspended you would either see it waking up or have to push power to wake it up.

Comment: What I mean is, if I close the lid and then unplug the laptop. It *should* suspend, but it doesn't, for reasons that I address in another question: http://superuser.com/questions/160000/how-can-i-make-kde-suspend-my-laptop-when-i-unplug-it-while-the-lid-is-already-cl I'm attacking the problem from two angles, and fake ACPI events is one of them.

Comment: Look in your /sys/power and see if there is an item for the lid. If there is, you can try writing a different state to it with echo -n "x" . I don't have linux on a laptop to see whats in there. (My source/thoughts from http://acpi.sourceforge.net/documentation/sleep.html)

Answer (score 0):

[ACPI-FakeKeys](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/acpi-fakekey) might do the trick.

Comment: There does not appear to be a lid button defined in `/usr/share/acpi-support/key-constants`, so I can't see how you would generate a lid event using `acpi-fakekey`